# Requesting Base64 encoded URL with Faraday in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, faraday

I need to get some Data from a server where the URL is provided to me as Base64. I usually use Faraday to connect to JSON APIs (which is the return format). Here is a basic example, including the error I get:

```
url = "data:application/json;base64,srighiuerghieurg..."
Faraday.get(url)

#=> URI::InvalidURIError: query conflicts with opaque
```

Opening the URL in any browser yields the expected JSON, but how can I make this work using Faraday?

To give you an idea of the structure of the request:

```
curl 'https://some.site.net/1/indexes/*/queries?some-agent=...' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Host: some.site.net' -H 'Origin: https://another.site.com -H 'Referer: https://another.site.com/some/path' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240' --data '{"requests":[{"index":"some-name","params":"some=params"}]}'
```

Comment: can you check whether the protocol is present in the url (http/https)

Comment: @Sajin It's not. The above is everything I got.

Comment: Have you tried to decode url from Base64, and than use that value as URL ?

Comment: @Nermin I have tried a couple of webbased decoders, but no luck with any of them.

Comment: what is the url that works for you in browser?

Comment: @Sajin Unfortunately I am not at liberty to disclose the real URL

Comment: Ok, I get it. Do you mind modifying the actual url and share the structure of the url you are passing to faraday so that we can get an idea

Comment: @Sajin I added a sample curl where you can see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

You probably need to split on the first `,` then `.decode64` on the remaining?